# The "/tags/{tags}/wikis" API does not return the proffered "body_last_edit_date" or "excerpt_last_edit_date" fields

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

The API for [`/tags/{tags}/wikis`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags) offers `body_last_edit_date` and `excerpt_last_edit_date` fields.

Both are selected in the default filter. But neither are actually returned even for tags I'm 100% sure have wikis and/or excerpts.

[Try this query with a custom filter to return only the last edit dates ...](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags#tags=syd;sfo;usa;tickets;automobiles;australia&filter=!n2nZcg%281rg&site=travel&run=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of some typos, those fields were being queried for... and then discarded immediately.

A fix has been deployed.